# Trying to do a stacked bar plot--ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot using the green, yellow, and brown data columns. I have been trying for about 4 hours to get something, anything that resembles the plot I am looking for, but it is not working. I am hoping someone can help me!

I am hoping to get the data by season and year. I can attach a sketch if that would be helpful!

I have attached the data set using dput!

Thank you so much!

```
structure(list(Group.1 = c("Dry", "Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Dry", 
"Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Wet"), Group.2 = c(2014, 
2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 
2020), Season = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Month = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Year = c(2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 
2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020), Date = structure(c(1408464000, 
1416441600, 1435622400, 1436068800, 1467720000, 1467754971.42857, 
1499212800, 1499241600, 1530345600, 1530835200, 1562184000, 1562299200, 
1579780800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Site = c(5.33333333333333, 
5.33333333333333, 5.72222222222222, 5.72222222222222, 7.71428571428571, 
7.21428571428571, 7.83333333333333, 7.76190476190476, 7.85714285714286, 
7.85714285714286, 7.85714285714286, 7.85714285714286, 7.85714285714286
), PercentCover = c(0.897777777777778, 0.878888888888889, 0.831666666666667, 
0.725555555555556, 0.676666666666667, 0.686190476190476, 0.807142857142857, 
0.865238095238095, 0.867142857142857, 0.839047619047619, 0.776666666666667, 
0.80952380952381, 0.81), AveHt = c(45.2214646464646, 46.8260381593715, 
54.949214365881, 44.4990179573513, 55.0315098261527, 50.7637987012987, 
64.539917027417, 61.1960076960077, 65.4478930461073, 60.7889739229025, 
61.2646919879063, 65.2833994708995, 65.5714285714286), SE = c(6.25553984399914, 
6.31783891047163, 7.03447757871604, 5.79283592248656, 6.89567924812464, 
5.41501015322623, 7.891615542892, 6.20637360205532, 7.01436253023661, 
6.62282377122733, 8.52215129612555, 8.331357660327, 7.14285714285714
), MaxHt = c(76.8333333333333, 80.5555555555556, 86.9444444444444, 
70.2777777777778, 81.3095238095238, 70.2380952380952, 97.5952380952381, 
87.3809523809524, 95.7142857142857, 90.3571428571429, 99.5238095238095, 
100, 102.5), green = c(NaN, NaN, 0.393510431109336, 0.0663154040347023, 
0.365637822536709, 0.201368231543444, 0.281001365778443, 0.281952721605167, 
0.185459801045249, 0.346027845615739, 0.252340369608337, 0.139236999167285, 
0.0221428571428571), yellow = c(NaN, NaN, 0.384359796082841, 
0.782121480112796, 0.506947037039218, 0.669662709760724, 0.596585207531189, 
0.644847772240803, 0.707306036947104, 0.53298032719581, 0.633770702365847, 
0.6153402143547, 0.658571428571429), brown = c(NaN, NaN, 0.222129772807823, 
0.151563115852502, 0.126929231774899, 0.128969058695832, 0.122413426690368, 
0.07319950615403, 0.105402660176144, 0.112514193710817, 0.111747916582478, 
0.243266532672145, 0.317857142857143), Temp = c(82.8888888888889, 
78.1111111111111, 81.3055555555556, 76.8888888888889, 80.8095238095238, 
75.8333333333333, 81.1190476190476, 76.7857142857143, 80.8780487804878, 
76.1578947368421, 82.1190476190476, 77.0238095238095, 74), Temp_C = c(28.2716049382716, 
25.6172839506173, 27.391975308642, 24.9382716049383, 27.1164021164021, 
24.3518518518519, 27.2883597883598, 24.8809523809524, 27.1544715447154, 
24.5321637426901, 27.8439153439153, 25.0132275132275, 23.3333333333333
), Vis = c(1.94166666666667, 1.89444444444444, 1.80555555555556, 
1.48333333333333, 1.71904761904762, 1.89761904761905, 2.27380952380952, 
2.42857142857143, 2.41190476190476, 2.21666666666667, 2.2775, 
2.50714285714286, 2.55714285714286), Nests = c(11, 4.88888888888889, 
18.6666666666667, 7.52777777777778, 6.88095238095238, 4, 11.9024390243902, 
6.11904761904762, 6.61904761904762, 4.69047619047619, 11.1904761904762, 
10.8095238095238, 4.92857142857143), SickorDeadFish = c(0.666666666666667, 
0.444444444444444, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0833333333333333, 0.19047619047619, 
0.404761904761905, 0.119047619047619, 0.119047619047619, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.0952380952380952, 0.0952380952380952, 0.0731707317073171, 0.0714285714285714
), Cladophora = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.118666666666667, 0.0942857142857143, 
0.0504761904761905, 0.0590476190476191, 0.01, 0.0166666666666667, 
0.0285714285714286, 0.0361904761904762, 0.0128571428571429), 
    Comments = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 
    NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data has 13 columns, and you don't mention any of them... except for `season` which is all missing for your sample data, and `Year`. What do you want to put on the x-axis? What do you want to put on the y-axis? When you say *"am hoping to get the data by season and year"*, can you be more specific?

Comment: Gregor Thomas is right be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want so I would suggest next sketch using the variables you mentioned with the data you included `df` from your `dput()` in the post:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Select data
dfn <- df %>% select(c(Group.1,Group.2,green,yellow,brown))
#Melt
dfp <- dfn %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2))
#Plot
ggplot(data=dfp[dfp$Group.2!=2014,],aes(x=Group.1,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = position_stack())+
  facet_wrap(.~Group.2,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

As this is a example, I removed data for `2014` but in your real data you must have full values.